# ZStream ignores parallel operation and executes it sequentially instead

Tags: scala, zio

Following code is supposed to execute `putStrLn` effect in parallel because of `mapMPar`:

```
val runtime = zio.Runtime.default
val foo = ZIO.sleep(5.second) *> ZIO("foo")
val bar = ZIO("bar")

val k = ZStream.fromEffect(foo) ++ ZStream.fromEffect(bar)
val r = k.mapMPar(3)(x => console.putStrLn(s"Processing `${x}`"))

runtime.unsafeRun(r.runDrain)
```

But in fact it always process `foo` before `bar` no matter what. Did I miss something or it's a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your example just doesn't do what you expect it to do. `fromEffect` creates a stream which basically says "I have an effect that will eventually generate a single item", the first stream then waits 5 seconds before producing that item. Due to the nature of the stream the `++` or `concat` operator is lazy, meaning it can't start processing until all items have been *consumed* from the first stream (which can't happen for 5 seconds). As a result your stream really looks like this:

```
--5s--(foo)(bar)|
```

instead of what I imagine you think it should like:

```
(bar)--5s--(foo)|
```

The best way to perhaps think about it is that for most of the stream you have a single lane highway, only one item can move at a time, and all subsequent items are blocked by items at the head of the line. Once you hit that `Par` block you are opening up to multiple lanes of traffic, meaning that faster moving stuff could potentially overtake.

Thus I can achieve the desired behavior by doing something like this instead:

```
val k = ZStream("foo", "bar")
val r = k.mapMPar(3)(x => putStrLn(s"$x:enter") *> (ZIO.sleep(5.second) *> putStrLn(s"Processing `${x}`")) <* putStrLn(s"$x:exit"))

r.runDrain
```

Or written slightly more compact:

```
ZStream("foo", "bar").mapMPar(3)(x => for {
  _ <- putStrLn(s"$x:enter")
  _ <- ZIO.sleep(5.seconds) *> putStrLn(s"Processing `$x`")
  _ <- putStrLn(s"$x:exit")
} yield ()).runDrain
```

Comment: This make sense, but it doesn't look like this is how it should work in parallel mode. Because let's say I have complicated code and decided to use `mapMPar` in some method. In that method I don't actually know how this stream was produced, so I can't trust that `mapMPar` will do its job. Moreover, such behaviour means that I can't concatenate streams if I want to parallelize them which is also sounds strange to me.

Comment: It will work in parallel mode, the issue is with where you are expecting parallelism to kick in. Inserting the delay on the first effect doesn't actually generate parallel behavior because you are delaying the whole stream, so both items still get submitted to the parallel work queue in the same order with no asynchronous boundary between them, meaning they will still output in the same order.

Comment: "that I can't concatenate streams if I want to parallelize", It sound like you actually want to `merge` the streams, not concatenate them. And again the issue is with how the items get submitted, only a single value can be submitted at a time to the work queue (in other words serialized processing), its just that `mapNPar` allows multiple items to be processed in parallel _within the operator_